# Error upgrading dependencies in yarn.lock file with yarn up in Yarn 2.0

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, dependabot, yarn-lock.json, yarn-v2

I'm trying to use Yarn 2.0 to upgrade to the latest version of the dependency in my `yarn.lock` to resolve a dependabot issue. The issue exists with the `ini` dependency and I tried running command `yarn up ini` which resulted in the following error:

```
❯ yarn up ini
Usage Error: Pattern ini doesn't match any packages referenced by any workspace
```

I noticed that I can use `yarn up` to upgrade packages in `package.json` file, but haven't been able to figure out how to update a dependency in a `yarn.lock`. I'm wondering if anyone knows what command I should be using instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Documentation Source: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#renamed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that you can't upgrade individual dependencies in the `yarn-lock` file, you have to upgrade package with the dependency in the `package.json` file by running the command:

`yarn up ${package_name}` followed by `yarn install` in Yarn 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that I can use yarn up to upgrade packages in package.json file, but haven't been able to figure out how to update a dependency in a yarn.lock. I'm wondering if anyone knows what command I should be using instead?

Starting from 3.0, transitive dependencies (ie dependencies of dependencies) can be upgraded using `yarn up -R <name>`.